# Backup Operating System with Softwares Installed

Tags: windows-7, backup, windows-backup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Looking for a software capable of cloning a System drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/61317/looking-for-a-software-capable-of-cloning-a-system-drive)

I am using a Dell Laptop with Windows 7 installed,as i have installed softwares like photoshop, Netbeans and other developing software and use to update it. As i recovery my PC i have to all again install the Softwares again and again.

> Is there any method or software where i can backup my OS along with the softwares installed so that when i restore, i may be able to use my softwares too without any new installation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes. Easy. Make a full backup of the whole disk. Either with the win-7 build in backup tools, or with a disk image program such as Norton Ghost, Acronis, CloneZilla or one of many others.

Keep that image in a safe place (not on the laptop itself).

When you need to recover from a disaster you can just re-image the whole disk, or a single partition. This works remarkably well if you partition your drive in two separate volumes, one for the OS (to be recovered) and one for data.

Comment: Thankyou can i know like how can i backup as you said and then if my OS crashes, then if i have to boot a CD/DVD with my softwares, how can this backups help me using when booting too ? Please Help

Comment: In a nutshell for the win7 build in: Select the drive, right click, tools, backup now. For restoring them: IF the OS still works: Start -> All Programs -> Accessories -> System Tools, system restore.  Else: Boot the windows iso (either from a DVD or a pen drive). Do not select reinstall but choose the smaller button "System restore".

Answer (score 1):

My vote would be for [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/), to be used for imaging the hard disk. It's free, easy to use, and then you can have a complete image stored in a safe location should disaster strike.

Comment: Does Clonezilla have booting image option, for eg if my os crash can i boot and restore the OS + the softwares with clonezilla, is yes how ? Help -

Answer (score 0):

Through the control panel

- You can create "Restore Points".
- You can make a "System image"
- You can make a "Backup"

[Restore Points](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378910(v=vs.85).aspx) may be the best fit for you.

> Restore points are created to allow users a choice of previous system states. Each restore point contains the necessary information needed to restore the system to the chosen state. Restore points are created before key changes are made to the system.